# ASP.NET Core app is behind a ssl proxy server and Reply to URL is http:// not https://

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET Core Application on an IIS server listening on whatever.domain.com/virtual-dir usings . The outside world accesses it through a ssl accelerator. Its using [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/) for OpenId authentication through AzureAd.

Because of the SSL proxy the app things its base address scheme is http as opposed to https (`http://whatever.domain.com/virtual-dir` vs `https://whatever.domain.com/virtual-dir`. This leads to it sending a reply-to address of `http://whatever.domain.com/virtual-dir/signin-oidc` as opposed to `https://whatever.domain.com/virtual-dir/signin-oidc`. I can modify the callback endpoint with [OpenIdConnectOptions.CallbackPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.remoteauthenticationoptions.callbackpath?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_RemoteAuthenticationOptions_CallbackPath), but that is only relative to the base Url. How do I change the base url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directions for this is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1#when-it-isnt-possible-to-add-forwarded-headers-and-all-requests-are-secure

Breakdown:

1. You're proxy needs to set three Http Headers, `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Host`
2. You need to configure [ForardHeaderOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.forwardedheadersoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1). In theory IIS should do this for you.
3. In `Startup.Configure()` you need to call `app.UseForwardedHeaders();` before `app.UseAuthentication()` so the the `Request` base is rewritten.

Comment: I tried this in .net core 2.1, but it does not work.  My base address is still http.  I am hosted on IIS and using cloudflare (where the http to https redirects happen).

Answer (score 1):

**Don't do this. This is a bad idea.**

<s>The best way I've figured out how to do this so far is to set [OpenIdConnectOptions.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.onredirecttoidentityprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to a function and in that function you can edit the ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri in the [RedirectContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.redirectcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1) parameter that gets passed.</s>

```
/// <seealso cref="OpenIdConnectEvents.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider"/>
public async Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext redirectContext)
{
       redirectContext.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri =
           "https://whatever.domain.com/virtual-dir";
}
```

Comment: please explain why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Actually, this is a great idea. My issue was that the redirect URI had to go through the reverse proxy because the host's own URI would be blocked by the firewall. Being able to overwrite the redirect URI is essential for that flow to work.